# Simplify nth Roots $6\sqrt[3]{9000} + 7\sqrt[3]{576}$

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

I'm having some concerns about how I am going about simplifying this radical expression. I wanted to know if this would be an accurate method of solving.

Simplify:
$$6\sqrt[3]{9000} + 7\sqrt[3]{576}$$

Radical expression product rule & greatest common factor:
$$6\sqrt[3]{125}\sqrt[3]{72} + 7\sqrt[3]{8}\sqrt[3]{72}$$

Principle of nth root:
$$6 \cdot 5\sqrt[3]{72} + 7 \cdot 2\sqrt[3]{72}$$

Simplify:
$$30\sqrt[3]{72} + 14\sqrt[3]{72}$$

Addition of radical rule:
$$30 + 14\sqrt[3]{72}$$

Simplify:
$$44\sqrt[3]{72}$$

Is $44\sqrt[3]{72}$ completely simplified?
I'm positive that 72 has no whole number $a$ that satisfies $72 = a^{3}.$

Comment: You'd do better to factorise $9000$ and $576$ products before you begin manipulations. You can go down to prime factors if necessary, but $9000=10^3\times 9$ is obvious and the obvious factor $9$ gives $576=64\times 9=4^3\times 9$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write "I'm positive that 72 has no whole number $a$ that satisfies $72 = a^{3}$". However, simplifying also works if there $72$ has a *cubic factor*. And indeed, $72$ contains a cube $a^3=8$. So we get $88\cdot \sqrt[3]{9}$.

Comment: Yes, I completely missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \sqrt[3]{9000} = (9 \times 10^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} = 10 \times 9^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$ \sqrt[3]{576} = \sqrt[3]{(2^3 \times 3)^2} = 4 \times 9^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$ 6\sqrt[3]{9000} = 60 \times 9^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$ 7\sqrt[3]{576}  = 28 \times 9^{\frac{1}{3}} $$

$$ 7\sqrt[3]{576} +  6\sqrt[3]{9000}  = (60 \times 9^{\frac{1}{3}}) + (28 \times 9^{\frac{1}{3}})  = 88 \times 9^{\frac{1}{3}} $$